# How to Output Account Name Merge Tag with Dashes

Tags: custom-field, merge

When I use the account name merge tag {!Account_AccountName} to output the name of an account in an email message it shows up something like: Georgia’s Hair Salon. However, I'd like to somehow be able to output it like this: Georgia’s-Hair-Salon. Is there any way to make that happen?

Comment: is there a pattern that you would like for eg: replace all spaces with - in the text?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I'm actually looking to use this in a text message. I'm trying to create a link that includes the output from the merge tag in a parameter, but it breaks the link in a text (works fine in an <a> tag).

Comment: can you try {!substitute(Account_AccountName,' ','-')} this just replaces the  space with -

Comment: I'll give that a try, give me just a minute!

Comment: let me know if your issue is solved

Comment: I just tried sending that through an email and it didn't work. Is there a merge tag for substitute? Maybe I need to use that to create a custom merge tag. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9247/discussion-between-rao-and-jeremiah-prummer)

Comment: If you don't mind sacrificing some control, You can use URLENCODE (e.g. {!URLENCODE(Account.Name)}). It will replace " " with "+", and most special characters with %XX values. The links will be compliant with HTML standards, so email applications (GMail, etc) will correctly render the link.

Comment: @rao helped me figure this out. Just ended up using a custom field.

Comment: Jeremiah, can you add that as an answer? It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer; it all helps make the question useful for others in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with a custom field which works brilliantly. Since the information I needed already existed in an account record, here's what I did:

1. Logged in and clicked my name dropdown at the top and then clicked the setup tab.
2. From there I went to Customize->Accounts->Fields.
3. Half way down the page is a section titled 'Account Custom Fields & Relationships', where I clicked the "New" button.
4. Step 1: Select field type "Formula"
5. Step 2: Set a field label and a field name and select formula return type 'text'.
6. Step 3: Paste the following into the textarea: `substitute(Name,' ','-')` You can optionally add a description and help text at the bottom of the page.
7. Save it and click next.
8. Step 4: Select which user type you want to have access to this field. This will vary from one organization to the next
9. Step 5: Select which pages you want this to be available on. Again, this varies.
10. Click save and you're done!

**Notes:** If you're doing this for a Contact or Lead record you'd obviously want to do modify those fields instead of the Account field. However, the process should be basically the same.

Also, in `substitute(Name,' ','-')` you can change out name with any of the merge fields available in Step 3.

Hope this helps anyone else with this issue!